# Duplicate the rows to get N results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with N rows, and I want to select I results, with I possibly > N.

So if my table T has 3 row A, B & C, and I = 5 want my query to return
A, B, C, A, B

Has anyone achieved to to this?
Thanks

Comment: If you want actual help you are going to need to provide actual details. Table definition (as create statement), sample data (as inserts) and desired output.

Comment: My bad for that, I will try to be more precise next time

Comment: Why wait till next time? You can edit your question...

Comment: Is the number of rows you want in the output ever more than twice the number of rows in the table?

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH RECURSIVE sequence AS (
  SELECT 1 AS num
  UNION ALL
  SELECT num + 1
  FROM sequence
  WHERE num < 12
)
SELECT c1.customer_id
FROM (
    SELECT (num - 1) % (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Customers) + 1 AS idx
    FROM sequence
) AS sub
JOIN Customers c1 ON c1.customer_id = sub.idx
ORDER BY sub.idx;
```

assuming that 12 is the number of rows you want to select and the table has 5 rows, this worked during my testing, try this assuming the table name is Customer and that each row has an id column to state the row number and the id column (primary key) is called customer_id, so adjust these to your column name and table name and the number of rows selected is 12 so change that accordingly as well.

Comment: This will work but using a recursive cte to generate numbers can be problematic unless the number of rows needed is small. Using a tally table or the new [Generate Series](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/generate-series-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) might be another approach.